# Show phpmyadmin cell in html textbox value

Tags: php, textbox

I have a database in phpmyadmin called `fleet hire motors`, and in that database is a table called `customer`.

In that table are columns called `customerID` and `Surname`. I have already done some coding on one page that lets the user select the `customerID` to edit the `Surname`.

On the next page I want a textbox. in that textbox, the default value should be what the current `Surname` is.

So, if i was to edit customer with `customerID` 1 (of which surname is currently `Brown` and I want to change to `Green`) the second page would show `Surname: [Brown]`, where [] encloses a textbox.

I currently do not have any code, and would like to keep it primarily php. The first page is called `editcustomer.php`, and the second is called `editcustomer2.php`.

Any help is appreciated.

My current code is:

```
<html> <head> <title>Edit Customer</title> </head><body>
<?php mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("fleet hire motors") or die(mysql_error()); ?> 
<?php 
$CustomerID = $_GET["CustomerID"]; 
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = '$CustomerID' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    b$CustomerID = $row["CustomerID"]; 
} ?> 
First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="
<?php  
    $FirstName = $_GET["CustomerID"]; 
    include 'db.php'; 
    $query=mysql_query(" SELECT FirstName  FROM customer  WHERE CustomerID = '$CustomerID' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
?> ">
<br> <input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Save"> <input name="resubmitbtn" type="submit" value="Reset"> </form> </body> </html>
```

Sorry for all the edits, as I am new to stackoverflow and just learning how to do it.

I have now updated my coding thanks to a response, but it is still not working. My most current coding is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("fleet hire motors") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php 
$CustomerID = $_GET["CustomerID"]; 
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = '$CustomerID' ") or         die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if (!$row || !is_array($row)){
$CustomerID = 0;
$CustomerFirstName = '';
}
else {
$CustomerID = $row["CustomerID"]; 
$CustomerFirstName = $row['FirstName'];
}
?> 
First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="<?php echo $CustomerFirstName; ?  >">
<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Save">
<input name="resubmitbtn" type="submit" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not give me anything in the textbox, and my submit button does not work.

Comment: can you insert your current code for this?

Comment: show what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make an echo.
In case that your customerId shall be unique you did not need a while.

```
[...]
<?php 
$CustomerID = $_GET["CustomerID"]; 
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = '$CustomerID' ") or     die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
if (!$row || !is_array($row)){
    $CustomerID = 0;
    $CustomerFirstName = 'NoNameFound';
}
else {
    $CustomerID = $row["CustomerID"]; 
    $CustomerFirstName = $row['FirstName'];
}
//Debug
echo 'rowcontent: <pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';
?> 
First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="<?php  
    echo $CustomerFirstName;
?>">
   [...]
```

You should also do some validation on your GET and POST before using them in your database e.g.

```
is_numeric($CustomerId)
```

or something like

```
[...] WHERE MD5(CustomerId) = ' . md5($CustomerId) . ' [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this does not seem to be working for me.Do I insert this code after line 3? would you please be able to demonstrate the whole code to show where to put this? Thank you.

Comment: You have to close the php-tag correctly. You did it `? >` and it must be `?>`. Instead of `$CustomerFirstName = ''` you can try `$CustomerFirstName = 'NoNameFound';` to check if the row was found.

Comment: what is the output of that line: `echo 'rowcontent: <pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';`?